# Exclude and disable holidays in jquery UI datepicker diff between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/e90dpe15/). I'd been trying to disable holidays with this array

`var array = ["2016-03-21","2016-03-24","2016-03-25"]`

But doesn't works, in different ways like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/4550kLym/) but nothing.

And also I need that in the diff of the two dates exclude the holidays in the array.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but the article and its comments seem convincing enough to suggest it's probably going to work for you: https://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

Comment: Now the disable dates works, thank you, but the diff still counting that days.

Comment: I don't think any cal-picker will give you that functionality. Maybe, sort special dates, and subtract the count of any that are between your diff-range. e.g. date1 - date2 - array_segment.length